# Cannot login to OpenManage Server Administrator

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dell, dell-openmanage

After freshly installed OpenManage Server Administrator from the CD that comes with my new server, Dell PowerEdge T110, I still could not figure out how to login successfully to the application. The server is running Windows 2008 SR2 Foundation and serves as a domain controller.

I access its web interface locally using Firefox 3.6. On the login page and choose local system login. [OMSA user's guide](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/svradmin/6.4/en/UG/HTML/index.htm) seems to state that I should be able to login using an Active Directory user. I tried `Administrator`, `my_domain\Administrator`, a a few combinations with the correct password. But none of them can logged in.

Does Server Administrator requires any additional treatment to the user accounts, or what are the steps I missed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it actually turned out that the tried-and-true method, restarting, does fix the problem. I'm not quite understand why and the documentation doesn't seem to mention it. But after the server had rebooted, I can logon with the domain admin account just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This questions is old, but since I had the same problem and couldn't find the solution here, I'd like to share with you my experience and the solution I found:

Under the security tab in Internet Options click the Custom Level button for the zone in which you've added the address of your server and in User Authentication > Logon select the option "Automatic logon with current user name and password".

This solution worked fine for me and I hope it would be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 1):

I come across with the same problem.. What worked for me was, to use the username:

`.\Administrator`

which indicates the local domain.

> NOTE: If the server where SupportAssist Enterprise is installed is a
>   member of a Windows domain, you must provide the user name in the
>   [Domain\Username] format. For example, MyDomain\MyUsername. You can
>   also use a period [ . ] to indicate the local domain. For example,
>   .\Administrator.
>   
> Souce: [Dell Support](http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/gr/el/grdhs1/supportassist-enterprise-v1.0/sae10ug/logging-in-to-supportassist-enterprise?guid=guid-258e5ad7-3445-4331-ae9a-0382d0f91344&lang=en-us)

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the dsm services and was able to login with active directory credentials.